# Aerospike lua scripting issue

Tags: lua, aerospike

We are running a little POC with Aerospike to understand if we can run LUA scripts doing some stuff.

In this case, we used the flights example:
https://github.com/aerospike/flights-analytics

I created a new index on the flight time in order to search by it.

The script runs over all the records and finds the last arrival time of a flight.
We inserted only flights to Bufalo for simplicity sake.

```
    local function aggregatCityToMax(result, record)

      city = string.upper(record['DEST_CITY_NAME'])
      flightTime = record['ARR_TIME']


    if result[city] == nil then

           info("CITY: |%s|      |        DATE: %d        |        MAX: null" , city, flightTime)
           result[city] = flightTime

    else

            info("CITY: |%s|      |        DATE: %d        |        MAX: %d" , city, flightTime, 
        result[city])

         if result[city] < flightTime then
           info("new MAX %s", flightTime)
           result[city] = flightTime
         end
    end

   return result

end

local function reduce_values(a, b)
   return map.merge(a, b, mergeFunction)
end


local function mergeFunction(a, b)

   info("merging:  %s VS %s ", a, b)

   if a < b then
       return b
   end

   return a
end

function mapMax(stream)
 return stream :  aggregate(map(), aggregatCityToMax) : reduce(reduce_values)
end
```

The log shows odd result:
1. I don't get the maximum. 
2. It looks like every 10 records, the maximum value is reset to null.

LOG:

CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1253        |        MAX: null
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1221        |        MAX: 1253
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1600        |        MAX: 1253
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1203        |        MAX: 1600
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1424        |        MAX: 1600
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2141        |        MAX: 1600
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1821        |        MAX: 2141
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1221        |        MAX: 2141
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1424        |        MAX: 2141
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1550        |        MAX: 2141
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1703        |        MAX: **null**

CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2312        |        MAX: 1703
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2251        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 19        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1030        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1257        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 803        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 19        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1502        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2319        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1735        |        MAX: **null**
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1221        |        MAX: 1735
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1258        |        MAX: 1735
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2125        |        MAX: 1735
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2251        |        MAX: 2125
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1104        |        MAX: 2251
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2053        |        MAX: 2251
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1340        |        MAX: 2251
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2312        |        MAX: 2251
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2226        |        MAX: 2312
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2053        |        MAX: **null**
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1637        |        MAX: 2053
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1030        |        MAX: 2053
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1618        |        MAX: 2053
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1510        |        MAX: 2053
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1510        |        MAX: 2053
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2346        |        MAX: 2053
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2343        |        MAX: 2346
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1600        |        MAX: 2346
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1550        |        MAX: 2346
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1949        |        MAX: **null**
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 1104        |        MAX: 1949
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2045        |        MAX: 1949
CITY: |BUFFALO|      |        DATE: 2213        |        MAX: 2045

Did I do something wrong?
Did I miss anything?

Thanks,

Idob

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike's aggregation is more of streaming in nature. i.e it keeps pushing partial results out so that there is no stalling. The reduce which happens at the client will do the final job of merging all the partial results. This is a different model compared to hadoop map-reduce where the reduce/final will wait for all the local reduces to finish completely before starting itself. There is a merit in the streaming model of Aerospike.

You have a print statement in the aggregate function. Once the partial result is pushed out, the seed map will start as empty when it is working on the next batch. There is nothing wrong in your logic. The end result should be fine. Are you seeing any issue with the end-result ?